# finding phpmyadmin setup username and password

Tags: phpmyadmin, installation

I'm using phpmyadmin 3.4.11.1deb1 on ubuntu 12.10.I want to increase the limitation of file upload but when I try `localhost/phpmyadmin/setup` an authentication dialog box appears which require user name and password. I've entered my phpmyadmin username and password but it didn't work.how can I find a true user name and pass for that?

Answer (score 0):

try admin username with no password